# POWERSHELL: Regex Find and replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to search and replace parts of UserObject paths using regex.

If you query windows for Users in Local Groups it returns the members as in the example below. Local users are displayed with an domain related prefix and i want to find this domain prefix an delete it form local user paths.

```
Return Value:

\\MyDomain\PCTest\John Doe   #(Local User)
\\MyDomain\Julie Doe         #(Domain User)

After Formating: (how can i do this?)

\\PCTest\John Doe             #(Local User)
\\MyDomain\Julie Doe          #(Domain User)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the first element if the path contains more than two elements:

```
'\\MyDomain\PCTest\John Doe','\\MyDomain\Julie Doe' | Foreach-Object{

    if( ($items = $_.Split('\',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)).Count -gt 2)
    {
        '\\'+ ($items[1..$items.count] -join '\')

    }
    else
    {
        $_
    }
}

\\PCTest\John Doe
\\MyDomain\Julie Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

supposing your values are stored in c:\temp\users.txt :

```
gc C:\temp\users.txt |%{if ($_ -match "local"){$_.replace("MyDomain\","")}}
```

edit :

```
$slices="\\MyDomain\PCTest\John Doe".split('\')
if($slices.Count -eq 5){wh "\\$($slices[3])\$($slices[4])"}
```

Comment: Hi, Local and Domain are comments they're not appering in the file/object. My start value is an array with mixed entries like in the Example RETURN VLAUE obove. In this arry are multiple entries for domain and local users. I only want to Trim/Replace the Domain referenz form the local user like "John Doe" above.

Answer (score 0):

```
"\\MyDomain\PCTest\John Doe", "\\MyDomain\Julie Doe" | % {
  $_ -replace '\\MyDomain(\\.*\\)', '$1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
'\\MyDomain\PCTest\John Doe','\\MyDomain\Julie Doe' |
ForEach-Object {
'\\{0}\{1}' -f $_.split('\')[-2,-1]
}
```